# How to install cpanm with github action workflow with linux runner?

Tags: perl, github-actions

I am not able to install [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus) with this simple workflow:

```
name: linux-cpanm-test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build-dist:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: perl info
        run: |
          perl --version
      - name: install cpanm
        run: cpan App::cpanminus
      - name: test cpanm
        run: cpanm -v Path::Tiny
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-gha-cpanm/runs/1787186872?check_suite_focus=true) to the test repository. As can be seen, `cpan App::cpanminus` fails with:

```
Use of uninitialized value $_[0] in substitution (s///) at /usr/share/perl/5.30/File/Basename.pm line 341.
fileparse(): need a valid pathname at /usr/share/perl/5.30/CPAN/FirstTime.pm line 1413.
Error: Process completed with exit code 255.
```

Any ideas what can be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [shogu82148/actions-setup-perl](https://github.com/shogo82148/actions-setup-perl). That installs `cpanm` for me and I've never had any problems.

The `jobs` section of my workflow files look like this:

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        os: ['ubuntu-latest', 'macos-latest', 'windows-latest']
        perl: [ 'latest' ]
    name: Perl ${{ matrix.perl }} on ${{ matrix.os }}
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up perl
        uses: shogo82148/actions-setup-perl@v1
        with:
          perl-version: ${{ matrix.perl }}
      - run: perl -V
      - run: cpanm --installdeps .
      - run: prove -lv t
```

Comment: Thanks for the reference to the action `shogo82148/actions-setup-perl@v1`. It seems it will install `perl` from source is that correct? I am trying speed it up by using the pre-installed perl on the Ubuntu runner together with a local lib for cpan modules.

Comment: @HåkonHægland: To be honest, I haven't looked into what it does in any detail. I'm pretty sure it doesn't build Perl from scratch though - it doesn't take long enough.

Answer (score 2):

In my Github workflows, I don't use cpan to install cpanminus. I've run into issues with openssl on the ubuntu hosts.

```
        - name: Install cpanm and multiple modules
          run: |
            curl -L https://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
            cpanm --notest ...
```

But, I also break my workflows for different platforms into separate files. See [PerlPowerTools/.github/workflows](https://github.com/briandfoy/PerlPowerTools/tree/master/.github/workflows) for instance. That one is not very complicated.

I don't spend the time to try to make them all act like each other—that's too much complexity. I don't want to debug someone's action when it's not doing exactly what I want. Also, when one platform has a problem, I can create a branch and trigger just that platform on that branch. You might be able to do that with a single file runner too, but that's too much complexity for me to want to manage.

Also, I've had lots of spurious failures with CPAN mirrors with a bare call to cpan. I've updated all of my actions to point to the CDN version of CPAN and haven't seen that problem since:

```
cpan -M https://www.cpan.org ...
```

And, lately I've been careful to install dependencies first using the "no test" features of either client. This mostly saves a lot of time. After that, I then run the tests for my module:

```
cpanm --notest ...
cpan -T ...
```

Comment: I like the idea of having a separate file for each host type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `cpan App::cpanminus` tries to install `local::lib` into `/home/runner/perl5/`. I tried to bootstrap [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) manually to `$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/perl5` instead. This seems to fix the problem (I am not sure why, but I guess it has to do with permissions):

```
name: linux-cpanm-test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build-dist:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: perl info
        run: |
          perl --version
      - name: setup locallib
        run: |
          tempdir=$(mktemp -d)
          cd $tempdir
          wget https://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/H/HA/HAARG/local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
          tar zxvf local-lib-2.000024.tar.gz
          cd local-lib-2.000024
          PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=$GITHUB_WORKSPACE/perl5
          perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT
          make
          make test
          echo "PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PERL5LIB=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/lib/perl5" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base \"$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/\"" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          echo "PATH=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/bin:$PATH" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: install cpanm
        run: cpan App::cpanminus
      - name: test cpanm
        run: cpanm -v Path::Tiny
```

Here is a [link](https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-gha-cpanm/runs/1787343658?check_suite_focus=true) to the new build log, showing that it now works.

**Edit**:

Here is a simplified workflow file as suggested by @ikegami. This also works:

```
name: linux-cpanm-test
on: [push, pull_request]
jobs:
  build-dist:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: perl info
        run: |
          perl --version
      - name: setup locallib
        run: |
          PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT="$HOME/perl5"
          >>"$GITHUB_ENV" echo "PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT"
          >>"$GITHUB_ENV" echo "PERL5LIB=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/lib/perl5"
          >>"$GITHUB_ENV" echo "PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base \"$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/\""
          >>"$GITHUB_ENV" echo "PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT"
          >>"$GITHUB_ENV" echo "PATH=$PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
      - name: install cpanm
        run: cpan App::cpanminus
      - name: test cpanm
        run: cpanm -v Path::Tiny
```

[Here](https://github.com/hakonhagland/perl-gha-cpanm/runs/1793785228?check_suite_focus=true) is the log.

Comment: It's also rather inexplicable when you go through the effort of installing `cpanm` when `cpan Path::Tiny` would work just as well.

Comment: I've found that cpan out of the box often had spurious errors on the ubuntu runners, often related to poor mirror selection or openssl issues. Since cpanm bypasses the mirror completely, the first issue is solved. And cpanm can install IO::Socket::SSL on older perls, then avoid the openssl issues.

Comment: @ikegami *"Use this as the entire "setup locallib" step."* Thanks, it works fine!